# How to zoom all pages in Chrome?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extensions

I needed to switch to different display size due to WFH. Sometime connecting to desktop from laptop using remote desktop, sometime connecting the laptop to monitor etc. I needed to change my chrome zoom level in this cases and I didn't find any short cut to do it other than going through the settings->page zoom every time. Is there a way to do it?

So finally...

How to zoom in/out all the open pages in chrome using keyboard shortcut?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: How to zoom in/out all the open pages in chrome using keyboard shortcut?

Comment: I don't think that is possible by default, but you could write a script to set the default zoom for you.